# How to disable IPv6 redirect?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I need to disable IPv6 redirect in my system (a router), and I got this error:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.send_redirects=0
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/send_redirects: No such file or directory

root@hostname:~$ uname -a
Linux hostname 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please provide the results of `uname -a` into the question.

Comment: @Rinzwind I add the `uname -a` info, thx

Answer (score 2):

Kernel doesn't support `send_redirects` for IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `net.ipv6.conf.all.send_redirects` option to disable ICMPv6 redirects. But you can

**Block the redirect packets in ip6tables**

```
sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type redirect -j DROP
```